# Google App Script to notify change on particular tab of the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a notification rule on a google sheet when changes are made to a specific tab of the sheet.

I found some google app script and tweaked it but I continue to get an error message as below. What can be done to fix this?

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeType' of undefined

Code:

```
    function notify(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (sheet == 'Analytics Project' && e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW') {
    MailApp.sendEmail('test@gmail.com', 'Row Added', 'A row was added to your sheet.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation / Issue:**

Your goal is to use an [onChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) trigger.

You need to understand the following two concepts:

- Triggers (as the name suggests) are functions that are executed upon events. However, you are trying to manually execute this function but you are not supposed to do that because `e` is not defined and therefore you are getting a message that the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e` is undefined. Therefore, don't run it manually, but instead insert a new row and you will see that your script will do its job.
- This is an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable), namely you need to create an `onChange` installable trigger for `notify`.

To create an installable trigger, execute **only** and **once** the `createTrigger` function:

```
function notify(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  if (sheet == 'Analytics Project' && e.changeType == 'INSERT_ROW') {
    MailApp.sendEmail('test@gmail.com', 'Row Added', 'A row was added to your sheet.');
  }
}

function createTrigger(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("notify")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onChange()
  .create();
}
```

[image]